# What is the right way to report follow-up information on a question?

Tags: discussion

Before Pesach I asked [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15285/seder-advice-when-with-people-who-arent-interested) about ways to engage people at the seder.  I received several good suggestions and attempted to implement some of them.  I'd like to -- somehow -- update the question to report on what I did and what happened.

Should I post it in an answer, by editing the question, by leaving a series of comments (won't all fit in one), or something else?  Does SE have conventions for reporting experimental results (where questions are not of simple fact)?  What's the right way to share what I've learned?

Comment: I have no idea how to tag this question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your experiences serve to answer your question, please do write them up as an answer, just like you would if you asked a question and then did more research and came up with an answer yourself. If not, you can consider putting them in as an aside at the end of the question, perhaps below a horizontal rule.